# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

**My simple query showing this error**

```
DB::table('news')->join('categories', 'news.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
->join('users', 'news.created_by', '=', 'users.id')
->select('news.*', 'categories.name as category_name','users.name as user_name','categories.bn_name','users.photo','news.photo as n_photo')
->where('status', 1)
->orderBy('news.id', 'desc')
->take(5)
->get();
```

Answer (score 20):

try to change this:

```
->where('status', 1)
```

to this:

```
->where('news.status', 1)
```

Probably you have in another join table another field called `status` so you need to specify the table where you want to filter by `status`.

Comment: Thanks, @alessandro

Comment: Glad to help you @FaridulKhan ! Please accept the answer when you can to help other person with your same problem

Comment: Sorry, i can't. only arifur can because he question it.

Comment: I haven't seen that you aren't the user that has make the question :D